# Emails only seem to being sent to gmail

Tags: php

I'm using some code to send data to a database which also sends a confirmation email to the email address that was entered into the form field

For some strange reason, it only seems to send to my gmail account and nothing else like hotmail tiscali yahoo

Here's the code I'm using to send the email

```
 // this send the receiver an email with the link to their ecard
 mail("$receiveremail","Somebody loves you !", "<img src=\"http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk/images/email-header.jpg\" width=\"300\" height=\"57\"> 
 </p>
 <p>Hello $name,</p>
 <p>Someone you know has sent you a secret valentine's message from http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk </p>
 <p>You can view your message here : <a href='http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk/viewcard.php?rand=$eid'>http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk/viewcard.php?rand=$eid</a></P>
 <P>Why not send a special someone a secret valentine's message at http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk</p>
 <P>Happy Valentines", $headers); 

 // this send the receiver an email with the link to their ecard
 mail("$youremail","View the message you've just sent", "<img src=\"http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk/images/email-header.jpg\" width=\"300\" height=\"57\"> 
 </p>
 <p>Hello,</p>
 <p>Thanks for using Somebody Loves You </p>
 <p>You can view the message you sent here : <a href='http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk/viewcard.php?rand=$eid'>http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk/viewcard.php?rand=$eid</a></P>
 <P>Happy Valentine's", $headers);?>
```

I was advised to use these headers as well to help sending the emails but it doesnt seem to work

```
 // these headers are for the purpose of sending the email replay to hotmail and yahoo addresses
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: SOMEBODY LOVES YOU <hello@somebodylovesyou.co.uk>\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Reply-To: <hello@somebodylovesyou.co.uk>\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.2800.1409\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook Express 6.00.2800.1409";
```

Comment: You should look into something like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), or [Pear](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected). Try one, and see if it works for you.

Comment: Did you tried it with a simpler email body? (no html, less text)

Comment: Try a throwaway service like `mailmetrash.com` or `10minutemail.com` and see if it arrives there.  If it does, but still not yahoo/hotmail, verify that it's not ending up in spam.  There's a good chance that if you're on shared hosting, most email providers will mark it spam.

Answer (score 1):

Technically Gmail is exactly the same as any other e-mail service when it comes to the protocol, so I guess it's not a code-related problem.

What I'd check is your outgoing e-mail server and domain, especially two things:

- [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records
- [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM) signature

These are e-mail forgery prevention techniques. Some e-mail services will automatically reject any mails without SPFs and DKIM.

Comment: Do MX and DNS records count as well? I don't know much about email protocols but I remember these were an issue when I last dealt with an email issue

Comment: MX record is used for incoming mail, so it should be OK. DNS records is a broad term for all those domain-associated records, including MX, SPF and DKIM. Check your domain registrar's website for some tips about configuring SPF and DKIM.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) It's very easy to utilize and it is very robust

```
$body = "<img src=\"http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk/images/email-header.jpg\" width=\"300\" height=\"57\">   </p>  <p>Hello $name,</p>  <p>Someone you know has sent you a secret valentine's message from http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk </p>  <p>You can view your message here : <a href='http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk/viewcard.php?rand=$eid'>http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk/viewcard.php?rand=$eid</a></P> <P>Why not send a special someone a secret valentine's message at http://www.somebodylovesyou.co.uk</p>  <P>Happy Valentines</p>";      
    $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

     $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
     $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
             ->setFrom(array("hello@somebodylovesyou.co.uk" => "SOMEBODY LOVES YOU"))
             ->setTo(array($receiveremail))
             ->setBody($body, 'text/html');

$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: From that code, how do i send the 2 different emails to $youremail and $receiveremail? Alos, so i just replace what I have with that code or do i need to include some other files?  im quite lost at the moment

Comment: You should have approached this problem differently in the beginning. What I am going to say is not efficient but I believe you're in your learning stages. Have $body1 and $body2 variables one for $receiver and the other one for $youremail. Duplicate $message1 for receiver and $message2 for youremail. Change the variables accordingly and you're good to go until you learn OOP.

Comment: do i need to include any other files or just replace what i have?

Comment: Include SwiftMailer. 
require_once('swift/lib/swift_required.php');
Take a look at their documentation http://swiftmailer.org/docs/including-the-files.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is not an issue with your code. If it's arriving to one mail provider but not another then the other providers are blocking it or marking it as spam.

At this point what you want to look into ensuring MX records and other DNS records are correctly set to identify your server.

It's also possible that your domain / IP has been blacklisted. In that event each mail provider has steps you can take to get off their blacklist.

Comment: seems the emails are going straight to junk mail... any way of preventing this?

Comment: This is a question better suited for serverfault.com. It will essentially boil down to setting public records to say that you're not a dirty spammer. May involve getting yourself removed from blacklists.